# Delete and update row in DataSet(C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net, oledb

My form:

[image]

I want delete selected row in dataset. Button "Delete" has this handler:

```
            int indexForDeleting = 0;
            bool reason = true;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                if (reason)
                {
                    indexForDeleting = item.Index;
                    reason = false;
                }
            }
            dataSet11.flight.Rows.Remove(dataSet11.flight.Rows[Math.Abs(indexForDeleting)]);
            dataSet11.flight.AcceptChanges();
```

Selected row deleted only in DataGridView, but I want delete row in DataGridView and DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

If that grid is bound to a DataTable, then delete the DataRow of that table, rather than the grid row. Something like this:

```
int rowIdx = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[rowIdx].DataBoundItem;
DataRow dr = drv.Row;
dr.Delete();
```

That will delete the row and update the grid as well.

Comment: does't solve the problem, row deleted only datagridview

Comment: Yes it does. DataRow.Delete() sets the RowState property of the row to Deleted. When you update that DataSet / DataTable to your database, with adapter typically, it will add/update/delete the rows, according to their RowState.